# Jquery - propertychange not on each entered symbol

Tags: jquery

I'd like to show only one "Updated" instead of multiple ones (one per entered symbol). And, also - as this sends ajax request (not shown in the code) - I'd like to send changed data "in bulk" -  not a separate ajax request per entered symbol (h,e,l,l,o) but, rather, **"an ajax request per entered word... or each 2 seconds..."** to minimize Db load. I could use change() but I need to update on paste event also. Here is the code:

```
   $(':input').bind("input propertychange", function() {

      var thiss = $(this);
      setTimeout(
        function() {
          thiss.after('<span>Updated!</span>');
        }, 2000);

    });
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/un3b5gks/

Comment: google -> "javascript debounce"

Comment: Thanks man! looks like this is exactly what I need.... digging into this. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for those in need (thanks Andreas!!!):

```
function debounce(fn, delay) {
  var timer = null;
  return function() {
    var context = this,
      args = arguments;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      fn.apply(context, args);
    }, delay);
  };
}


$(':input').bind("input propertychange", debounce(function(event) {
  var thiss = $(this);

thiss.parent().append('<div class="updated" style="color: green">Updated!</div>').children(':last').hide().fadeIn(200).delay(1000).fadeOut(200);


}, 666));
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/un3b5gks/3/

To get more info on "debounce":

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

https://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls